# GLSL uchar input shared with OpenCL

Tags: opengl, glsl, opencl, shader

**Code architecture**

I want to visualize some particles which are updated through OpenCL. The particles have a position and a type attribute. The position is stored as three floats while the type is a unsigned char. In the visualization the position is updated correctly but if I try to include the type the buffer updates are no longer visible from the OpenGL side (more on that later).

The types are used as input data for a shader (I'm using [OGLplus](http://oglplus.org/)):

```
buffers.particle_types.Bind(gl::Buffer::Target::Array);
(*program | "particle_type")
    .Setup<GLubyte>(1)
    .Enable()
    .Divisor(1);
```

`.Setup` basically expands to

```
VertexAttribIPointer(loc, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, 0)
```

In the vertex shader the input is defined as...

```
in int particle_type;
```

I'm not sure if this is correct - From the host side the data type is set to `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` - My expectation is that the conversion is done on the fly? Something like `in uchar particle_type` doesn't work.

The update code looks basically like that

```
std::vector<cl::Memory> gl_buffers{
    particle_types,
    particle_positions
};

glFinish();
cl_queue.enqueueAcquireGLObjects(&gl_buffers);
simulation.update(); // reads from / writes into buffers
cl_queue.enqueueReleaseGLObjects(&gl_buffers);
cl_queue.finish();
```

**Problem description**

When the visualization is active it seems like the updates to the types-buffer are not visible on the OpenGL side. This means that the visualization is wrong. I've als tried to read the opengl-buffer into the host memory through `glGetBufferSubData` which doesn't get updated either. The interesting thing is that the data received from `glGetBufferSubData` is up to date if the visualization is disabled. So my expectation is that I've done something wrong there.

It also seems like the sharing itself is correct because I don't have issues with the position data.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: This is an interesting question. `glVertexAttribPointer` is supposed to accept `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, however, GLSL has no byte-sized scalar type. So I assume it will convert the data to the next possible type, which is `int`. Did you declare the GLSL variable as `int`?

Comment: glampert: Yes I did. I've also did some further testing and changed my whole code to use `int` instead of `uchar` for all calculations (which is suboptimal because I affects performance) and it works. On the other hand I still couldn't find anything related that the above code isn't supposed to work.